# Why am I getting 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'beep'?

Tags: python, class, object, oop

```
class Vehicle():
    def __init__(self,price,color,gas):
        self.price = price
        self.gas = gas
        self.color = color
    
    def hello(self):
        print('hi how are you?')

    def fillUpTank(self):
        self.gas = 100

    def emptyTank(self):
        self.gas = 0

    def gasLeft(self):
        return self.gas


def Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self,price,color,gas,speed):
        super.__init__(self,price,color,gas)
        self.speed = speed 

    def beep(self):
        print('Beep Beep!')

    def hello(self):
        print('beep!')


jim = Vehicle(200,'blue','petrol'`
jim.hello()
tim = Car(500)
tim.beep()
```

When I tried to run jim.hello(), it showed no error but it was when I tried to run tim.beep()

Comment: `class Car(Vehicle)`, not `def Car` ? The indentation may be wrong as well.

Comment: Also you need to provide the other arguments for your `tim = Car(500)`. i.e. the color, gas, and speed.

Comment: You defined `Car` as a function with a single parameter `Vehicle` instead of as a class that inherits from `Vehicle`. Closing to vote as a typo. (The only thing the function `Car` does is define three local functions that never get used, then (implicitly) returns `None`.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Answer (score 0):

Please use `class` keyword before `Car` class not `def`.
Actually you are defining `Car` as a function, please use the `class` keyword to define it as a class.

```
class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self,price,color,gas,speed):
        super.__init__(self,price,color,gas)
        self.speed = speed 

    def beep(self):
        print('Beep Beep!')

    def hello(self):
        print('beep!')
```